# what are the factors that affect the value of motionevent.getx()?

Tags: android, imageview, motionevent

i am doing an app to show the coordinate when i touch on the screen. however, different devices show different range of coordinate. Here is my question.

1. Is it because of screen resolution?
2. how can i know the max coordinate of an image?
3. what are factors that affect the result of motionevent.getx()?

Answer (score 0):

**MotionEvent** will sometimes return absolute X  relative to the view, and sometimes relative coordinates to the previous motion event.

**getRawX()**  that is guaranteed to return absolute coordinates, relative to the device screen.

While **getX()** , should return you coordinates, relative to the View, that dispatched them.